# 3D U-net - python metrics / loss function / accuracy seems innapropriate

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I am trying to transpose a pre-build 3D U-net in python (**keras**) for my brain dataset in python (https://github.com/ncullen93/Unet-ants, not mine). 
My dataset is composed of small tumors (150 - 1500 voxels) regarding to the whole brain volume but with high tumors to background ratio (~3).

I also dispose of a manual segmentation volume (with 0 for extra tumoral and 1 for voxels' tumor).

[18F-FET PET image and segmentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl2Sl.png)

Code is perfectly working (I use `categorical_crossentropy` as loss function) but there is a disrepency between the high accuracy

cf after 100 epoch :

```
loss: 0.0356 - acc: 0.9848 - categorical_crossentropy: 0.0356 - val_loss: 0.0399 - val_acc: 0.9825 -  val_categorical_crossentropy: 0.0399
```

and segmentation results as it always predict 0 (which is in accordance with the wide majority of voxels but is of no interest).

I don't know where or how I should start to improve those results. I allready have tried to change size of batch, number of filter, convolutional & deconvolutional kernel size, and learning rate without any significant improvements.

Thanks for your help. Best regards

Paul

Comment: Try to increase a `class_weight` of a positive class.

Comment: Is your output a one-hot encoded vector of many classes or just a yes/no binary? -- If you've got only one yes/no, result, use `binary_crossentropy`, as you don't really have "categories".

Comment: thanks ! `binary_crossentropy` worked perfectly!